# I would like to sort strings in a numerical manner

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

I have a sorting function binded with an inverting arrow button for an exam score column

However I can't figure out how to sort them correctly

The code below returns

[N/A, N/A, 99%, 90%, ... 20%, 100%, 10%, 0%]

to

[0%, 10%, 100%, 20%, ... 90%, 99%, N/A, N/A]

and vice-versa

```
      // Score Sort
      if(this.scoreSort && this.sortColumn === 'Score'){
        const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
          const titleA = a.Score ? a.Score : '';
          const titleB = b.Score ? b.Score : '';
          if(titleA > titleB){ return this.scoreSort ?  1 : -1 }
          if(titleA < titleB){ return this.scoreSort ? -1 :  1 }
          return 0;
        });
        return sortedData;
      } if(!this.scoreSort && this.sortColumn === 'Score') {
        const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
          const titleA = a.Score ? a.Score : '';
          const titleB = b.Score ? b.Score : '';
          if(titleA > titleB){ return this.scoreSort ?  1 : -1 }
          if(titleA < titleB){ return this.scoreSort ? -1 :  1 }
          return 0;
        });
        return sortedData;
      }
```

How can I sort them in a manner like the array below?

[100%, 99%, 90%, ... 20%, 10%, 0%, N/A, N/A]

to

[0%, 10%, 20%, ... 90%, 99%, 100%, N/A, N/A]

and vice versa

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with [`numeric:true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#numeric_sorting) option like this:

```js
const input = ["N/A", "N/A", "99%", "90%", "20%", "100%", "10%", "0%"],
      sorted = input.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }))

console.log(sorted)
```